# lwc datatable: how to reenable scrolling after setting enableInfiniteLoading = false;

Tags: lightning-datatable

I have a lightning datatable with the infinite scroll working beautifully.

It properly loads a list of records, in paginated groups of 20 rows at a time.. and when it loads the completed list, it properly stops calling my `loadMoreData` handler because I set the `event.target.enableInfiniteLoading = false` on the prior iteration.

Now, if have a button on my page that causes the records to be refreshed (and we start over again with just the first 20 records) - I can not seem to find a way to reset the data-table to allow the infinite scrolling process again

I started with markup that looked like this (matching the specification)

```
 <lightning-datatable
       if:true={data}
       key-field={keyname}
       data={data}
       enable-infinite-loading
       >
 </lightning-datatable>
```

I also experimented with this version where I try to reset the behavior with a variable, but this hasn't worked either

```
 <lightning-datatable
       if:true={data}
       key-field={keyname}
       data={data}
       enable-infinite-loading={enableScrolling}
       >
 </lightning-datatable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to just do it in javascript:

```
this.template.querySelector("lightning-datatable").enableInfiniteLoading = false;`
```

(Not sure if this will work without a reload).

If it doesn't, try two datatables, one with

```
enable-infinite-loading
```

and the other without - and switch between then as desired using a boolean.